# navigate and show single div each time onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have three div's, when user clicks on "Click to see other Divs", next available div i.e.,Div2 should be shown and current div should be hidden.
Again if user clicks , Div2 should be hidden and Div3 should be shown. If user clicks for 3rd time and as their are no new div's to show, Div1 should be displayed.

Please find the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/56/
Please suggest javascript changes.

Below is sample javascript code:

```
  function navigate(){
    alert("navigate");
    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery if you're not using it?

Comment: If you *do* use jQuery this will be a lot shorter/simpler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this quick example for you and added in comments so it's easy to follow.

```js
// Add a "click" event handler to the element
document.getElementById("showDivs").addEventListener("click", function () {

    // Get all div's
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    // Get the visible div
    var visibleDiv;
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var id = divs[i].id;
        var index = divs[i].id.indexOf("Div");
        if (divs[i].style.display === "block" && divs[i].id.indexOf("Div") > -1) {
            visibleDiv = divs[i];
        }
    }

    // Hide the visible div
    visibleDiv.style.display = "none";

    // Get the number of the current div
    var divNum = Number(visibleDiv.id.replace("Div", ""));
            
    // Show the next div
    var nextDiv;
    if (divNum === 3) {
        nextDiv = 1;
    }
    else {
        nextDiv = ++divNum;
    }
    document.getElementById("Div" + nextDiv).style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
div{border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="showDivs" value="Click to see other Divs" />
<div id="Div1" style="display: block;">Div 1</div>
<div id="Div2" style="display: none;">Div 2</div>
<div id="Div3" style="display: none;">Div 3</div>
<div id="FixedDiv">Fixed Div</div>
```

This can be done with less code, however, for ease of understanding I used a lot of variables and commented every step of the way so you can see which parts of the code are doing what actions.

***EDIT***

In the edit, I added in a fixed div, just to show that the code will work if there are other div's on the page that aren't included in the div's that change.

***--- EDIT 2 jQuery Example ---***

Here's a jQuery example as requested with slide effects:

```js
// Add click event handler
$("#showDivs").click(function () {

    // Get the visible div
    var visibleDiv = $("div[id^='Div']:visible")[0];

    // Hide the visible div
    $("#" + visibleDiv.id).slideToggle();

    // Get the number of the current div
    var divNum = Number(visibleDiv.id.replace("Div", ""));

    // Get the number of the next div to show
    var newDiv;
    if (divNum === 3) {
        newDiv = 1;
    }
    else {
        newDiv = ++divNum;
    }

    $("#Div" + newDiv).slideToggle();
});
```

```css
div{border:1px solid black;width:100px;height:100px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="showDivs" value="Click to see other Divs" />
<div id="Div1" style="display: block;">Div 1</div>
<div id="Div2" style="display: none;">Div 2</div>
<div id="Div3" style="display: none;">Div 3</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort, thankyou. I was trying with slide effect, can you please suggest as i got the hide and show other div functionality. I'm trying jquery toggle but it's not working with dynamic div id. Here is the code i tried to toggle : var a = 1;
function navigate(){
   var id = "Div"+a;
   $(id).toggle( "slide" );
   document.getElementById('Div' + a).style.display = 'none';
    if(a>=3){
 a=0;
 }
    a++;
    document.getElementById('Div' + a).style.display = 'block';
} @Howard Renollet.

Comment: @user222 - This whole thing is a lot easier if you're using jQuery.  I'll post an update.

Comment: @user222 - answer updated with jQuery example with slide effects

Comment: Thanks it worked :), appreciate your effort. @Howard Renollet.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

**EDITED (since a back button wasn't necessary):**

```
var location = 1;

function navigate(){
        document.getElementById('Div' + location).style.display = 'none';
        location++;
        document.getElementById('Div' + location).style.display = 'block';
}
```

With the variable location it keeps track of what page is shown, starting with 1, then lets say we go forward, it will set the display of Div1 to 'none', then add 1 to the location variable to get 2, and then set the display of Div2 to 'block'.

Comment: Their is not back button, when user clicks on "Click to see other Divs" next available div should be shown and current div should be hidden, and if their are no available div then div1 should be displayed. Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/56/ . Thanks @Koen Hoeijmakers

Comment: In that case you just remove the operator part and the if else statement, and keep the 3 lines with location++

Comment: somehow the global variable declaration is not accepting and after Div3 again if user clicks on "Click to see other Divs" Div1 should be shown which is not possible with the mentioned javascript. Please suggest.Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/61/ .   @Koen Hoeijmakers

Comment: Is the amount of divs always 3?

Comment: No it might varry.@Koen Hoeijmakers

Comment: And does this amount have to be calculated by the computer or can you give it a fixed amount?

Comment: yes we can give a fixed amount, as of now 5 is maximum number of div's. Can we add any effect while showing other div like while div1 is hiding and div2 is shown some sliding effect. @Koen Hoeijmakers.

Comment: Here is a working example, http://jsfiddle.net/Neat/0p7djjnc/2/, you should now try to make the click event go to the first div when the you click it in the last div. (and for slide effects you should check the jQuery documentation)

Comment: This is an incomplete answer.  The OP states in the original question that when the last div is reached, the first div should be shown again.  Your example and your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Neat/0p7djjnc/2/) do not include this functionality.